# Rails protect_from_forgery with Mobile Apps

Tags: android, ios, ruby-on-rails-3, csrf, protect-from-forgery

I am building an app on Rails and I have the `protect_from_forgery` in my `application.rb`.  I have also built a RESTful API for mobile apps to communicate with using `JSON` data.  I see some sites that claim that in order for the mobile app to interact with the rails application, they turn off `protect_from_forgery` for JSON requests.

> How does this solve the problem of CSRF?  Can a malicious site not have JSON POST request that performs undesirable changes on behalf of the user?

So, to solve this problem , I decided to use a custom `mime-type` or perhaps a `special key` that only the mobile app would use, and then have `protect_from_forgery` perform the following:

1. Check if the csrf token is present as a `hidden div` (true for the web app and included by default).
2. If not present, check for this `special key` or `mime-type`.

Is there anyway to achieve this, or similar, to counter this problem?

**Update**

It turns out that I had over-thought the problem.  Rails is "magical" and somehow handled requests coming from a mobile app automatically and appropriately without raising an exception.  So, essentially we didn't have to make any modifications at all.

I didn't quite check how Rails achieves this though - pedagogically speaking, this might still be interesting to know for some.

Comment: How are the requests from the mobile app made?

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to use ActiveResources. If you send your request as xml then it'll bypass the protect_from_forgery.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d "<support-request><from>...</from></support-request>" -X POST http://localhost:3000/support_requests.xml -i
```

It should be pretty straightforward.